# Increase AWS VPC Subnet max instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, amazon-vpc, vpc

My AWS VPC has a CIDR of 10.0.0.0/16. 
The associated Route Table has Destination 10.0.0.0/16 set to target local.

The subnet has a CIDR of 10.0.0.0/24. There is a Route Table entry setting destination 10.0.0.0/16 to target local.

It seems these setting create a situation where the maximum number of instances I can run in the subnet is 250. The problem is that I would like to be able to run up to 800 instances in that subnet (that is my instance limit this region).

How can I adjust the subnet settings so that I can run up to 800 instances in it?

Answer (score 2):

And explanation of CIDR notation is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

A good tool for calculating your CIDR is here: http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr

Your issue is due to the fact that you chose /24 for your subnet, which only allows a maximum of 256 IP addresses. You would have to change that to something like /22, which would allow 1024 unique IP addresses in the subnet.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I've defined a new VPC and also a new Subnet in the new VPC with these larger settings. I can then migrate the instances over to the new subnet (AWS does not allow resizing an existing subnet and placing a new subnet in the same VPC with these larger settings conflicted with the existing subnet where I already have machines running).